# React Hook Form with MUI Autocomplete, FreeSolo and dependent fields

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm trying to create `ZipCode / City / State` (in Italian `CAP / Città / Provincia`) dependent fields from [this JSON file](https://github.com/matteocontrini/comuni-json/releases/download/2020-01-01/comuni.json) ([here's the repo as well](https://github.com/matteocontrini/comuni-json)). I'm using React Hook Form v7 and MUI v5.4.4. I'd like to implement this 3 fields using MUI Autocomplete component with `FreeSolo` props in order to let the user to insert a custom input value if it's not present in the JSON list.

I tried to make it works but it doesn't. How can I implement that? Furthermore, the validation for the Autocomplete component doesn't work.

[Here's the codesandbox that I wrote](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-feather-4niku7?file=/src/components/FormSections/PersonalDetails.jsx)

Comment: What do you mean by dependent? If the user selects a zipcode then then the city select should filter only cities with that zip code?

Comment: @knoefel yes, exactly. And viceversa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were several problems in your code:

- you forget to pass the `rules` prop to your `<Controller />`
- the current selected value will be passed as the second argument to `<Autocomplete />`'s `onChange` handler
- you need to use RHF's `watch` method to react to changes of those 3 dependent fields and filter the options of the other selects accordingly
- you need to use `flatMap` instead of `map` for the mapping of the options for postal codes, as `option.cap` is an array

```js
export default function PersonalDetails() {
  const { watch } = useFormContext();

  const { postalCode, city, state } = watch("personalDetails");

  return (
    <Card variant="outlined" sx={{ width: 1 }}>
      <CardContent>
        <Grid container item spacing={2}>
           <Grid item xs={12} lg={3}>
            <SelectFree
              name="personalDetails.postalCode"
              label="ZIP (CAP)"
              options={options
                .filter((option) =>
                  city || state
                    ? option.nome === city || option.sigla === state
                    : option
                )
                .flatMap((option) => option.cap)}
              rules={{ required: "Richiesto" }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} lg={10}>
            <SelectFree
              name="personalDetails.city"
              label="City (Città)"
              options={options
                .filter((option) =>
                  postalCode || state
                    ? option.cap.includes(postalCode) || option.sigla === state
                    : option
                )
                .map((option) => option.nome)}
              rules={{ required: "Richiesto" }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} lg={2}>
            <SelectFree
              name="personalDetails.state"
              label="State (Sigla)"
              options={options
                .filter((option) =>
                  city || postalCode
                    ? option.nome === city || option.cap.includes(postalCode)
                    : option
                )
                .map((option) => option.sigla)}
              rules={{ required: "Richiesto" }}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

```js
export default function SelectFree({
  name,
  rules,
  options,
  getOptionLabel,
  ...rest
}) {
  const { control } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      rules={rules}
      defaultValue={null}
      render={({
        field: { ref, ...field },
        fieldState: { error, invalid }
      }) => {
        return (
          <Autocomplete
            {...field}
            freeSolo
            handleHomeEndKeys
            options={options}
            getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                {...rest}
                inputRef={ref}
                error={invalid}
                helperText={error?.message}
              />
            )}
            onChange={(e, value) => field.onChange(value)}
            onInputChange={(_, data) => {
              if (data) field.onChange(data);
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit priceless-hamilton-pdxlww]

**UPDATE**

As you have a very large json file you have two options where you can optimise performance:

- limit the amount of options via the `filterOptions` prop of `<Autocomplete />` -> the `createFilterOptions` function can be configured to set a limit
- add a `useMemo` hook for the filtering and mapping of your options before passing them to the `<Autocomplete />`, e.g. right now on every input change for the other fields (`firstName`, `lastName`, `address`) the options will be recomputed

[image: Edit trusting-franklin-9rqbls]

Comment: Thanks, it seems to partially work. Using the "actual" `comuni.json` I receive this error for the ZIP and STATE fields: `Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `30020`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.` How can I insert the unique key?

Comment: The `codiceCatastale` should be the unique key.

Comment: Furthermore, there are a lot of duplicated results in the list. Maybe should I implement a sorta of custom filter? https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#custom-filter

Comment: I think it should be work like this but it seems a little bit slow. Maybe I can only show the first 10 results. Do you know how I can optimize it? What do you think? https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-architecture-2mqdms

Comment: Sorry, didn't have the time to look into this earlier. I updated my answer with your new requirement and added a second sandbox, check it out.

Comment: It seems to work like a charm now! Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Just asked another question. Do you know that as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71511930/react-hook-form-and-persistent-data-on-page-reload