# React Hook Form and persistent data on page reload

Tags: reactjs, persistence, react-hook-form

I'm using React Hook Form v7 and I'm trying to make my data form persistent on page reload. I read the official [RHF documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#WizardFormFunnel) which suggests to use [little state machine](https://github.com/bluebill1049/little-state-machine) and I tried to implement it but without success. Is there a better way to do it? However...

The first problem I encountered using it, is that my data is a complex object so the `updateAction` it should be not that easy.

The second problem is that I don't know when and how to trigger the updateAction to save the data. Should I trigger it on input blur? On input change?

Here's my test code:

[image: Edit busy-rgb-ljbo55]

Comment: By page reload do you mean if the user refreshes the whole app ?

Comment: @HugoBp What do you mean by “the whole app”? I mean, if the user clicks on browser refresh button the data is persistent.

Comment: Ok, I was indeed asking whether you were talking about persisting data on page change within your app because that's what the RHF documentation you linked talks about. Now I understand that's not what you are after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I already faced this issue and implemented it by creating a custom Hook called `useLocalStorage`. But since you are using the React hook form, it makes the code a bit complicated and not much clean!

I suggest you simply use the light package [react-hook-form-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-form-persist).
The only work you need to do is to add `useFormPersist` hook after `useForm` hook. Done!

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import useFormPersist from "react-hook-form-persist";

const yourComponent = () => {
  const {
    register,
    control,
    watch,
    setValue,
    handleSubmit,
    reset
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: initialValues
  });

  useFormPersist("form-name", { watch, setValue });

  return (
    <TextField
      title='title'
      type="text"
      label='label'
      {...register("input-field-name")}
    />
    ...
  );
}
```

Comment: This somehow doesn't work for me, I keep getting the defaultValues after refreshing the page

Comment: You have to verify your code. Please check this sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/xpujc

Comment: Literally copy pasted that into my project, doesn't work.

Any ideas @Hamidreza?

I made sure package versions are the same

Comment: https://github.com/tiaanduplessis/react-hook-form-persist/pull/32

Opened a PR, code works in production but fails using <React.StrictMode /> in development enviroment

Comment: @Borjante Have no idea until see your code. could you share your code via codesandbox? did you follow the sample code I already share? it works fine in my project.

Answer (score 9):

If persisting in the localStorage works you, here is how I achieved it.

Define a custom hook to for persisting the data

```js
export const usePersistForm = ({
  value,
  localStorageKey,
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [value, localStorageKey]);

  return;
};
```

Just use it in the form component

```js
const FORM_DATA_KEY = "app_form_local_data";

export const AppForm = ({
  initialValues,
  handleFormSubmit,
}) => {
  // useCallback may not be needed, you can use a function
  // This was to improve performance since i was using modals
  const getSavedData = useCallback(() => {
    let data = localStorage.getItem(FORM_DATA_KEY);
    if (data) {
     // Parse it to a javaScript object
      try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      return data;
    }
    return initialValues;
  }, [initialValues]);

  const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
    getValues,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({ defaultValues: getSavedData() });
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler = (data) => {
     // Clear from localStorage on submit
     // if this doesn’t work for you, you can use setTimeout
     // Better still you can clear on successful submission
    localStorage.removeItem(FORM_DATA_KEY);
    handleFormSubmit(data);
  };

  // getValues periodically retrieves the form data
  usePersistForm({ value: getValues(), localStorageKey: FORM_DATA_KEY });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      ...
    </form>
   )
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit my CodeSandbox example and show me how to do it in that specific case? I tried but it seems not work with my form example. I receive a lot of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'zip' of 'watch(...)' as it is undefined.`. As I wrote, I'm dealing with a complex state object.

Comment: I have edited the CodeSandbox, try it here https://codesandbox.io/embed/cool-nova-b8hsjs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I have edited the post it to fix the error, you have to parse object strings to javaScript object else it will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

The state itself won't persist any data on page reload.
You need to add your state data to Local Storage.
Then load it back into the state on `componentDidMount` (useEffect with empty dependency array).

```js
const Form = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({})
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(localStorage) {
      const formDataFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('formData');
      if(formDataFromLocalStorage) {
        const formDataCopy = JSON.parse(formDataFromLocalStorage)
        setFormData({...formDataCopy})
      }
    }
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage && localStorage.setItem("formData", JSON.stringify(formData))
  }, [formData]);
  
  const handleInputsChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        name="firstName"
        placeholder='first name'
        onChange={e => handleInputsChange(e)}
        value={formData?.firstName}
      />
      <input 
        type="text" 
        name="lastName"
        placeholder='last name'
        onChange={e => handleInputsChange(e)}
        value={formData?.lastName}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image: Edit gracious-hoover-oehb0w]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work for my example (please, check my CodeSandbox). I'm using RHF and my formData is a complex object.

Comment: I mean, using useEffect to set localStorage I think it could be a good idea the use `little-state-machine` but how can I update the whole RHF state object? I could watch every change using `methods.watch()` but then I should update the RHF state with the new one. How?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late, but I got it working by overwriting the default values. In my case, I needed to store my data in a global state, so it was a bit easy to implement this without a lib. But in order for this to work, you cannot reset your state.

Also, I believe that **kwaku hubert** and **Hao Zonggang** did basically the same thing, by using `LocalStorage` or the `usePersistForm` lib, which seems to work ^-^

```
const { selectedProduct, setSelectedProduct } = useProductsContext();

  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    getValues,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver<IAnnouncementRegistrationSchema>(
      announcementRegistrationSchema
    ),
    defaultValues: selectedProduct || DEFAULT_VALUES,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Cheers for [react-hook-form-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-form-persist).

Inherit from @Hamidreza Soltani answer. But faced some issue, when set `defaultValues`, page reload will not persist the storage, but it take the `defaultValues` instead. So, I've written a wrapper for the form.

```
export const usePersistForm = <
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
  TContext = any,
  TTransformedValues extends FieldValues | undefined = undefined
>(
  name: string,
  props?: UseFormProps<TFieldValues, TContext>
): UseFormReturn<TFieldValues, TContext, TTransformedValues> => {
  const hasStorage = window.sessionStorage.getItem(name)

  const form = useFormPrimitive<TFieldValues, TContext, TTransformedValues>({
    ...(hasStorage ? omit(props, ["defaultValues"]) : props),
  })

  useFormPersist(name, form)

  return form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use) has a `useLocalStorage` hook that comes in handy for this use case.

```
import { useLocalStorage } from 'react-use';

var Demo = () => {
    let [value, setValue, remove] = useLocalStorage('article', '',);

    let {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
    } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            article: value ?? '',
        },
    });

    let onsubmit: SubmitHandler<ArticleInputType> = (data) => {
        //...
        remove();
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onsubmit)}>
            <input
                {...register('article', {
                    required: 'This filed is required',
                    onChange: (e) => {
                        setValue(e.target.value);
                    },
                })}
            />
        </form>
    );
};
```